# Larger number of hugepages causing bus error

Tags: bus-error, dpdk, huge-pages

I was trying to run `dpdk` `timer` app by setting 512 2MB hugepages but the application crashed with following error

> EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)
>
> EAL: Probing VFIO support...
>
> Bus error (core dumped)

If I reduce the number of `hugepages` to 256 it works fine. I wondering what could be the problem here. Here's my cpu info

processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 26
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         950  @ 3.07GHz
stepping        : 5
microcode       : 0x11
cpu MHz         : 2794.000
cache size      : 8192 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_
perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida dtherm tpr_shadow vnm
i flexpriority ept vpid
bugs            :
bogomips        : 5600.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 26
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         950  @ 3.07GHz
stepping        : 5
microcode       : 0x11
cpu MHz         : 2794.000
cache size      : 8192 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_
perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida dtherm tpr_shadow vnm
i flexpriority ept vpid
bugs            :
bogomips        : 5600.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

And Here's my meminfo

MemTotal:       24679608 kB
MemFree:        24014156 kB
MemAvailable:   23950600 kB
Buffers:            3540 kB
Cached:            31436 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:            21980 kB
Inactive:          22256 kB
Active(anon):      10760 kB
Inactive(anon):     2940 kB
Active(file):      11220 kB
Inactive(file):    19316 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                32 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:          9252 kB
Mapped:            11912 kB
Shmem:              4448 kB
Slab:              27712 kB
SReclaimable:      11276 kB
SUnreclaim:        16436 kB
KernelStack:        2672 kB
PageTables:         1000 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    12077660 kB
Committed_AS:     137792 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:      2048 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:     256
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       22000 kB
DirectMap2M:    25133056 kB

Comment: I tracked down the problem. It was happening because I was running out of memory in /var/run. The DPDK uses /var/run to store hugepages information and because I only had 2MB of memory allocated for it, it wasn't sufficient for 512 hugepages. Increasing the memory allocation for /var/log solved the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your solution as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down the problem. It was happening because I was running out of memory in /var/run. The DPDK uses /var/run to store hugepages information and because I only had 2MB of memory allocated for it, it wasn't sufficient for 512 hugepages. Increasing the memory allocation for /var/log solved the problem.